# jQuery/JS - How to compare two date/time stamps?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two date/time stamps:

```
d1 = 2011-03-02T15:30:18-08:00 
d2 = 2011-03-02T15:36:05-08:00
```

I want to be above to compare the two:

```
if (new Date(d1) < new Date(d2)) {alert('newer')}
```

But that does not appear to be working correctly. Is there a way to compare not just the dates but the times as well.? thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
console.log(d1 + ' ' + d2);
console.log(new Date(d1) > new Date(d2))


2011-03-02T15:30:18-08:00 2011-03-02T15:36:05-08:00
false
2011-03-02T15:30:18-08:00 2011-03-02T15:30:18-08:00
false
2011-03-02T15:30:18-08:00 2011-03-02T14:15:04-08:00
false
```

Comment: Do you have those timestamps in string form, or do you actually have "Date" instances? (I ask because those assignment statements are syntax errors as they currently stand.)

Comment: False is the correct answer.  "2011-03-02T15:30:18-08:00" is not greater than "2011-03-02T15:36:05-08:00".

Comment: Also, something is weird in d1 for all but the first console messages.  They all start with "36:515"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your timestamps should be strings.

```
var d1 = "2011-03-02T15:30:18-08:00";
var d2 = "2011-03-02T15:36:05-08:00";

if (new Date(d1) < new Date(d2)) {alert('newer')}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hKPkF/

Comment: @patrick I'm not sure that the dates are parsed correctly. I get `Thu Mar 03 2011 00:30:18 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)` for the first one.

Comment: they are string, that was just a goof on writing up the question. so Date will compare not just the date but also to the time/secs level of detail./

Comment: @Šime Vidas: It is being parsed for your local timezone.

Comment: @Šime: Perhaps you're right. I didn't look that closely at the result. Still relative to each other they seem consistent.

Comment: I just update the Q, please take a look, it's always returning false

Comment: @AnApprentice: Yes, they will be compared as though you called `.getTime()`, which gives the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970.

Comment: @Jeff 15 + 8 = 0/24 - 1. Aha, got it.

Comment: @Patrick, thanks that's good to know. Still not sure why it's always returning false though?

Comment: @AnApprentice: Most of your `d1` timestamps appear to start with `36:515`, which renders it invalid.

Comment: that was extra stuff from firebug, just cleaned it up. sorry about that. Still same issue, it's not comparing the times. Do I need to maybe convert the timestamps to a string?

Comment: @AnApprentice: You didn't remove the `36:515` so I did, but are you sure that was just from firebug? When I remove those, it works fine. If it still doesn't work, then there's some issue not revealed in the question.

Answer (score 4):

You may be having trouble with the date string format. I am getting Invalid date if I do:

```
new Date("2011-03-02T15:30:18-08:00");
```

Here's what works for me on Chrome:

```
var d1 = "Thu Mar 03 2011 00:53:54 GMT+0100 (CET)";
var d2 = "Thu Mar 03 2011 03:53:54 GMT+0100 (CET)";

if (new Date(d1) < new Date(d2)) {console.log('newer')}
```

If you are working in ruby on the server side, you could convert to UTC from a `Time` object. Here it is, with a little massaging to convert to a format that is identical to javascript's Date object `toUTCString` method:

```
tm = Time.new
utc_tm = tm.getutc
utc_tm.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
```

Output: `"Thu, 03 Mar 2011 00:46:55 GMT"`

Comment: That does seem to be the issue, I'm in rails, is there a datestamp converstion I need to do?

Comment: Try converting to UTC, in the following format: `Thu, 03 Mar 2011 00:20:57 GMT`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work fine for me, although you have to format correctly (i.e. semicolons, quotes):

```
var d1 = "2011-03-02T15:30:18-08:00";
var d2 = "2011-03-02T15:36:05-08:00";

if(new Date(d1) < new Date(d2)) {alert('newer')};
```

And yes, it takes time into account.  If you do this:

```
alert(new Date(d1) - new Date(d2));
```

You get 347000, which is 347 seconds, or 5 minutes, 47 seconds.  This is the correct difference between the two.

Comment: Thanks but please see the above, it's always returning false.

Comment: Read my comments in the question.

Comment: Very interesting, if I do the (new Date(d1) - new Date(d2)) I get NaN

Comment: Maybe I can use rails to output a proper timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

var d1= '2011-03-02T15:30:18-08:00', d2= '2011-03-02T15:36:05-08:00';
Some browsers can convert an ISO string to a Date, with new Date or Date.parse.

A lot of browsers in use today cannot-you may need to write your own conversion.

This one seems to work, but it'll need refining. I added a shim for browsers that don't have an array.map, based on mozilla org's public code.

```
Date.fromISO= function(s){
    var day, tz, 
    rx=  /^(\d{4}\-\d\d\-\d\d([tT][\d:\.]*)?)([zZ]|([+\-])(\d\d):(\d\d))?$/, 
    p= rx.exec(s) || [];
    if(p[1]){
        day= p[1].split(/\D/).map(function(itm){
            return parseInt(itm, 10) || 0;
        });
        day[1]-= 1;
        day= new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, day));
        if(!day.getDate()) return NaN;
        if(p[5]){
            tz= parseInt(p[5], 10)*60;
            if(p[6]) tz += parseInt(p[6], 10);
            if(p[4]== "+") tz*= -1;
            if(tz) day.setUTCMinutes(day.getUTCMinutes()+ tz);
        }
        return day;
    }
    return NaN;
}
Array.prototype.map= Array.prototype.map || function(fun, scope){
    var L= this.length, A= [], i= 0;
    if(typeof fun== 'function'){
        while(i< L){
            if(i in this) A[i]= fun.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
            ++i;
        }
        return A;
    }
}
var d1= '2011-03-02T15:30:18-08:00', d2= '2011-03-02T15:36:05-08:00';
alert(Date.fromISO(d1)-Date.fromISO(d2)+' milliseconds')
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the differences in date formats and capability between browsers, I'd really reccomend you use a library devoted to DateTime handling. JS support for it is notoriously horrendous. I'm a HUGE fan of date.js

http://www.datejs.com/